# Is it possible to create a variable as a placeholder for 'current' value of a class in python?

Tags: python, oop, class, variables, placeholder

Let's say we have a class:

*NOTE: this is a dummy class only.*

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -10
        self.b = 5
        self.c = 2
    def modify(self, **kwargs):
        for keyword in kwargs:
            vars(self)[keyword] = kwargs[keyword]
        return(self)
```

And we want to use this modify method to change values in our object:

```
myclass = C()
myclass = myclass.modify(a=10)
```

But when I want to change the value based on the original one, I have to write this:

```
myclass = C()
myclass = myclass.modify(a=myclass.a/10)
```

Or:

```
myclass = myclass.modify(a=abs(myclass.a))
```

My question is, is there a way, to create a global variable in a module, that I can import and use it as a placeholder for current value, so I can use this formula:

```
from globvars import current

myclass = C()
myclass = myclass.modify(
    a=abs(current) % current ** 2,
    b=current//2,
    c=bool(current)
)
```

First I tried to a create a class, which will store the operation it is taking and a value, and `modify()` will look first for its variable as a keyword and then execute the function. Actually it is only working for simple situations like: `current+10` or `current**2`.
But when I realised, I want to use this `current` for example with an `hsba(current)` (*color converter*) function, where `current` is pointing to an object stored in an other object, I just give up, I can't write this to every class I'm going to use..

Is there a solution for this? Maybe it's quite easy, I just can't see it :)

Thanks in advance for replies!

Comment: It feels to me like you are massively over-complicating this. Why not just assign to the attribute like normal? Why is `myclass = myclass.modify(a=10)` better than `myclass.a = 10`?

Comment: Don't use `vars()` here; `for keyword, value in kwargs.iteritems(): setattr(self, keyword, value)` would work much more efficiently.

Comment: @Lattyware yes, I can use that, but in my situation, I want to check the inputs to validate them. That's why I choose this method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point, thanks! I will change that in my code!

Comment: @PeterVaro: Why not use `@property` then to create a setter that does the validation?

Comment: Can you do this?  -- Probably.  Would it be MASSIVELY complicated ... Yes.  Your `current` would need to be some sort of proxy object which returns more proxy objects anytime a method on it is called.  (e.g. `__add__`, `__nonzero__`, etc).  Each call would add a node to a tree which could be used to evaluate the ultimate expression given `self` and the key to be modified from kwargs (e.g. `'a'`).  However, There are definitely better ways.

Comment: @mgilson yes, this was my first attempt, and realised, that I have to write all the `__add__` and other valid operators, and all my custom operator overloads, and so on.. so that is definetly not the solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not familiar with decorators, but because of your comment, I just realised what they are good for. Thanks for that! Yes, `@property` could solve my problem, although if the object name is pretty long it could be really comfy to use `current` instead of writing the whole name over and over again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution. It is not complete and full of pretty bad design choices, but I hope it helps.

```
class Expr(object):

    def __init__(self, op, left, right):
        self.op = op
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __call__(self, current):
        l = self._replace_current(self.left, current)
        r = self._replace_current(self.right, current)
        return self._do_operation(l, r)

    def _replace_current(self, val, current):
        if val == 'current':
            return current
        elif isinstance(val, Expr):  # recurse
            return val(current)
        else:
            return val

    def _do_operation(self, l, r):
        if self.op == '+':
            return l + r
        elif self.op == '*':
            return l * r
        elif self.op == '-':
            return l - r

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._left_op('+', other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self._right_op('+', other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._left_op('*', other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self._right_op('*', other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self._left_op('-', other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self._right_op('-', other)

    def _left_op(self, op, other):
        if isinstance(other, Current):
            return Expr(op=op, left=self, right='current')
        else:
            return Expr(op=op, left=self, right=other)

    def _right_op(self, op, other):
        if isinstance(other, Current):
            return Expr(op=op, left='current', right=self)
        else:
            return Expr(op=op, left=other, right=self)


class Current(Expr):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Current, self).__init__(None, None, None)

    def __call__(self, current):
        return current

    def _left_op(self, op, other):
        return Expr(op=op, left='current', right=other)

    def _right_op(self, op, other):
        return Expr(op=op, left=other, right='current')


current = Current()


class YourObj(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __call__(self, **kw):
        for key, val in kw.iteritems():
            # You should probably make sure it is actually an attribute of YourObj
            if isinstance(val, Expr):
                current = self.a
                new_val = val(current)
                setattr(self, key, new_val)
            else:
                setattr(self, key, val)
```

And you can do something like:

```
obj = YourObj(a=4, b=5)
obj(a=current - 4 + current * current)
```

This is basically an expression interpreter embedded in python's math operations.

Whenever you use an operation on `current` (like +), it will return an `Expr` (because it overrides `__add__` and `__radd__`) that will register which operation this is, and what are each of its operands. These expressions can be nested, so if you say `current + 4 - current`, it will return `Expr(op='-', left=Expr(op='+', left='current', right=4), right='current')`.

An expression can then be evaluated by calling it like a function and passing it the value that should replace 'current'. When you evaluate an expression, it will:

- replace all the occurences of 'current' by the value passed
- recursively evaluate the nested functions
- return the end result of the whole expression

When you do `obj(a=current + 4)`, the `__call__` method of `YourObj` is called. It will evaluate the expression resulting of `current + 4` and store it in `a`.

I hope this is clearer. Maybe I should rename some of the 'current' to make it less confusing.

Comment: OK, I'm a bit confused now.. but a little more explanation would be nice:) What is in `Current` class? And when will the `Expr` class making an instance?

Comment: I added some explanations. Instances of `Expr` are created when you call a math operation on `current`, like `current + 4` (see in the `__add__` method of `Expr`). `Current` is a subclass of `Expr`.

Comment: I'm also adding an answer, my old solution.. I'm actually can't decide which one is 'nicer':/

Answer (score 0):

Your `modify` method could take the name of the attribute to modify, and a function that takes the current value of the attribute and returns its new computed value. Then you can do something like:

```
def compute_new_value(current):
    new_value = abs(current) % current ** 2
    return new_value

myclass = C()
myclass.modify('a', compute_new_value)
```

For simple cases, `lambda` makes it less verbose:

```
myclass.modify('a', lambda cur: cur + 4)
```

And your class:

```
class C(object):
    [...]
    def modify(self, attr_name, func):
        cur_value = getattr(self, attr_name)
        new_value = func(cur_value)
        setattr(self, attr_name, new_value)
```

**Edit**: I may have missed something. Since you're writing `myclass = myclass.modify...`, should the `modify` method return a *copy* of the object ?

Comment: Yes, modify function will return the original object itself. But that's not the problem with your solution. The problem is, that I have to define a new method, or even a lambda method, to do this. It is much more complicated, than writing this: `myclass.modify(a = abs(myclass.a) % myclass.a ** 2`. All I want is to make the code look much smoother, by adding this `current` placeholder, so I can use this: `myclass.modify(a = abs(current) % current ** 2)`. Easier to read and follow what is going on.

Comment: No, using a global variable is **never** easier to read and follow what is going on. Using a function describes exactly what you are doing: you are applying a transformation to the current value of your attribute. A transformation is exactly what a function is, and I don't think a `lambda` is too verbose for it.

Comment: At some point I completely agree with you! But can you take a look at my comments on @kindall 's answer? I write down my goal there, I hope that's an explanation not an excuse :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a poor design, in my opinion, but you *could* do this using `eval()`. Of course, that just makes your design smell even more. Still...

```
class C(object):
    # ...
    def modify(self, **kwargs):
        for name, expr in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, eval(expr, vars(self)))

obj = C()
obj.modify(a="a+2", b="b*42")
```

The downside is that you have to pass the expressions as strings. Also, with this simple implementation, you can only use values defined on the instance in the expression (e.g., you cant access class attributes, or any attributes of parent classes, or globals). You could add the ability to use class attributes or globals and even parent classes by building the `v` dictionary in the appropriate order, of course:

```
def modify(self, **kwargs):
    vardict = {}   # allow globals and self attributes to be used in expressions
    vardict.update(globals())
    vardict.update(vars(self))
    for name, expr in kwargs.iteritems():
        value = eval(expr, v)
        setattr(self, name, eval(expr, vardict))
        vardict[name] = value
```

If you want a `current` variable that holds the current value, you could use this (inside the loop, since it needs to change for each attribute processed):

```
v["current"] = getattr(self, name, None)
```

One of the biggest drawbacks here is that you can't easily access variables from the *caller's* scope, although you could dig them out of the stack frame I guess... ugh. Or make the caller interpolate those into the string... double ugh.

Morphyn's answer is the proper way to do it, in my opinion. A lambda is hardly complicated

Comment: Yeah, well it's always dirty to use strings to push expressions from one object to an other, and well for that matter `eval()` is also not the best way for doing things in our case. Actually, what you need to understand, is that I'm writing a 'superset'-like library for GUI markup and scripting. That's why I'm working on a quick and easy 'markup-style' coding with the power of python. This means, a designer, who will use my classes, will never see, what is inside a class, or how does it work, etc.

Comment: He will use it as `redbutton = rectangle(width=100, height=50)` and when he wants to modify it, later on in the script, he will call this item (`__call__`): `redbutton(width=current+100)`. That's where I'm getting, and what I wanted.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well I'm sorry to say that I don't know of a way to do this kind of magic.

Comment: There is a way to do it if you accept something like: `redbutton(width=curwidth+100, height=curheight+220)` but I'm not sure it makes it simpler than writing proper python.

Comment: @morphyn Well, thank you very much for the heads up.. It is somehow a relief, that it's not just me who don't know this kind of *magic* also the real python gurus don't know either:)

Comment: Well maybe a python guru will show up, I'm definitely not one ;) I actually tried to implement a solution where `current()` is a function  but I would need to access its dynamic scope, and even if I could  I don't see how it's possible to know to which attribute of your object it is bound at a given time. Like in `obj(a=current() + 4)`, even if I could access `obj`, how do I know it is bound to `a` and not `b` ? That's why I need a different name for each one, like `obj(a=cura + 4)`.

Comment: @morphyn Well, what I did at the first time was creating a class, which can produce `current`. And because it is an object, it can store the expression and the value also. Now, I'm added a few line of code to `modify()`, to check if input value is an instance of current. And when it is, it's looking for a previous value if there is one, and if there is, it will `eval()` the expression with the old and the new value. The problem was: I have to implement every single expression that can possible happen to `current` into its class.. So in this method, you don't have to know which value is what.

Comment: I finally wrote a solution. I will post it in another answer. Maybe this is similar to what you did ?

Answer (score 0):

This was my old solution.. (*sort of, this a dummy version of it*)

```
class __current__(object):
    def do(self, e, v = None):
        c = __current__()
        c.exp = e
        if v is not None:
            c.val = v
        return(c)
    def __abs__(self):
        return(self.do(abs))
    def __rpow__(self, v):
        return(self.do(pow, v))

current = __current__()

class C(object):
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        for keyword, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            try:
                expression = value.exp
                try:
                    value = expression(vars(self)[keyword], value.val)
                except AttributeError:
                    value = expression(vars(self)[keyword])
            except AttributeError:
                value = value
            setattr(self, keyword, value)
```

And the usage:

```
MyObj = C()
MyObj(a = -2)
MyObj(a = abs(current))
MyObj(a = 2 ** current)
```

Comment: Well... the basic idea is the same. In yours, the responsibility of knowing how to evaluate an expression is in `MyObj`, which I believe is not the best idea. And also, I think you will not be able to use `current` twice in the same expression (did not test it).